# How to add time in my script

Tags: scripting, time, openwrt

I have 3 scripts to build OpenWrt but I can't set it up to have time at the end.
Here's what the script gives and the script.
`openwrt-snapshot-r22256+29-14334c222e-ipq806x-generic-linksys_ea8500-sysupgrade.bin`

But I want that kind of description with time :
`openwrt-snapshot-r22256+29-14334c222e-20230310-ipq806x-generic-linksys_ea8500-sysupgrade.bin`

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# createbuildinfo 

SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
source ${SCRIPT_DIR}/shared

STATUSFILE="$BINDIR/$BUILTBASENAME.status"
DIFFFILE="$BINDIR/$BUILTBASENAME.patch"
DIFFCONFIGFILE="$BINDIR/$BUILTBASENAME.diffconfig" 

DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)

cd $BUILDROOT

echo "Creating build info for" 
echo " $BUILTBASENAME in"
echo " $BINDIR "

getGitInfo() {
#params: directory 
 echo "###########################################################################" 
 (cd $1
  echo -n "Repo   : "
  git remote -v show | grep fetch 
  echo -n "Branch : " 
  git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  echo -n "Commit : "
  git show --format="%cd %h %s" --abbrev=7 --date=short | head -n 1 | cut -b1-60 
  echo "Status : "
  git status --porcelain
 )
}

getGitDiff() {
 (cd $1
  git --no-pager diff HEAD 
 )
}


echo "Generating git statusfile $STATUSFILE" 

echo "Status for $BUILTBASENAME created $DATE" >$STATUSFILE 
echo " " >>$STATUSFILE

getGitInfo $BUILDROOT >>$STATUSFILE 

for feed in `cat feeds.conf | grep -v "^#" | awk '{print $2}'`
do
    getGitInfo $BUILDROOT/feeds/$feed >>${STATUSFILE}
done

echo "Generating diff file $DIFFFILE"
getGitDiff $BUILDROOT >$DIFFFILE

echo "Generating diffconfile $DIFFCONFIGFILE"
$BUILDROOT/scripts/diffconfig.sh > $DIFFCONFIGFILE
```

#shared

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH="snapshot"

BUILDROOT="/run/media/james/D/ipq806x_builds/NSS_test/"
BUILTDIR="$BUILDROOT/../builds"

VERSION_NUMBER=$($BUILDROOT/scripts/getver.sh)
VERSION_DIST=$(grep CONFIG_VERSION_DIST $BUILDROOT/.config | awk -F\" '{print $2}')
VERSION_DIST="${VERSION_DIST:=OpenWRT}"
TARGET_PROFILE=$(grep CONFIG_TARGET_PROFILE $BUILDROOT/.config | awk -F\" '{print $2}' | sed 's/DEVICE_//')
TARGET_SUBTARGET=$(grep CONFIG_TARGET_SUBTARGET $BUILDROOT/.config | awk -F\" '{print $2}')
TARGET_BOARD=$(grep CONFIG_TARGET_BOARD $BUILDROOT/.config | awk -F\" '{print $2}')

BUILTBASENAME="${VERSION_DIST}-${BRANCH}-${VERSION_NUMBER}-${TARGET_BOARD}-${TARGET_SUBTARGET}-${TARGET_PROFILE}"
BUILTBASENAME=$(echo $BUILTBASENAME | sed 's/ /-/g' | awk '{print tolower($0)}')

BINDIR="$BUILDROOT/bin/targets/${TARGET_BOARD}/${TARGET_SUBTARGET}"
```

#createbuild

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )
source ${SCRIPT_DIR}/shared

echo "#### `date`: Starting build of $VERSION_DIST $VERSION_NUMBER ####"

cd $BUILDROOT
time make -j4 V=s 2>&1 $1 | tee build.log | grep -i -E "^make.*(error|[12345]...Entering dir)"

if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -ne "0" ]; then
 echo -en "\007"
 echo "#### `date`: Build failed, bailing out... "
 exit 1
fi

echo -en "\007"
echo "#### `date`: Build of $VERSION_DIST $VERSION_NUMBER complete ###"

if [ -z $1 ]; then
    ${SCRIPT_DIR}/createbuildinfo

    echo "#### `date`: Moving completed build to $BUILTDIR/$BUILTBASENAME ####"

    mkdir -p $BUILTDIR/$BUILTBASENAME
    #mv -v $BINDIR/$BUILTBASENAME* $BUILTDIR/$BUILTBASENAME
    mv -v /run/media/james/D/ipq806x_builds/NSS_test/bin/targets/ipq806x/generic/*.bin /run/media/james/D/ipq806x_builds/builds/latest/

    rm $BUILTDIR/latest
    ln -s $BUILTDIR/$BUILTBASENAME $BUILTDIR/latest

    echo "All done! Sysupgrade file can be found in"
    echo $BUILTDIR/latest/$BUILTBASENAME-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
fi
```

Comment: That script does not seem to have anything obvious to do with creating a `*.bin` file. It seems to create three files (`*.status`, `*.patch` and `*.diffconfig`), whose names are determined by variables `$BINDIR` and `$BUILTBASENAME`, which are apparently both defined somewhere else and used as-is. Are you sure you copy/pasted the right script?

Comment: I have 3 others, see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the filename (or at least the parts that include the version identifiers) are built up in your second script (marked #shared), on the line:

```
BUILTBASENAME="${VERSION_DIST}-${BRANCH}-${VERSION_NUMBER}-${TARGET_BOARD}-${TARGET_SUBTARGET}-${TARGET_PROFILE}"
```

Since the `shared` script is sourced on the second non-empty non-comment line of your `createbuildinfo` script, your initialization of the `DATE` variable on the line:

```
DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
```

...happens too late. You must either move it to the beginning of the `shared` script, or to the beginning of your `createbuildinfo` script, before the line:

```
source ${SCRIPT_DIR}/shared
```

Once you've done this change, you could modify the assignment of `BUILTBASENAME` in the `shared` script as follows:

```
# original version commented out
# BUILTBASENAME="${VERSION_DIST}-${BRANCH}-${VERSION_NUMBER}-${TARGET_BOARD}-${TARGET_SUBTARGET}-${TARGET_PROFILE}"
# date included
BUILTBASENAME="${VERSION_DIST}-${BRANCH}-${VERSION_NUMBER}-${DATE}-${TARGET_BOARD}-${TARGET_SUBTARGET}-${TARGET_PROFILE}"
```

Note that the current definition of `DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)` results in a timestamp of the form YYYYmmdd-HHMM, i.e. it also includes the time. If you don't want that, create a date-only timestamp with `SHORTDATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)` in the beginning of either `createbuildinfo` or `shared`, and use `SHORTDATE` in place of `DATE` when constructing the value of `BUILTBASENAME`.

Comment: awesome for the date, thanks

Comment: only thing, the date has been added but on the directory not in the filename. (.bin)